# Installing Visual Studio Build Tools on Windows Container does not installs cl.exe

Tags: docker, windows-server, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

new to the containers and even newer to windows containers (!!!!)

I am aiming to use cl.exe to compile cpp programs on a windows container.

I am experiencing an issue installing Visual Studio Build Tools on a container with base image
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 or mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

I believe the cl.exe is integrated on the VCTools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools)

I order to check if the cl.exe was installed, I tried a local installation on my pc.
I usually find cl.exe at the following location.

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\
```

When performing the installation on the container on this same location, I only get the Auxiliary folder

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\Auxiliary
```

And not "bin" folder

I am building on a WindowsServerCore2022
I am building using DockerCe

So I am expecting to install cl.exe usually located on :

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\
```

I was greatly inspired on :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6VgI.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve it,
I think I misunderstood what was installed by using:

```
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
```

I thought the Workload installed all the components too as per :

> ```
> Components included by this workload
> ```

On [Workload's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022).

To solve this issue I had to install the component explicitly. Specifically, I required to add:

```
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
```